# D3.js Update Pattern Confusion

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a basic bar chart. A Bootstrap drop down menu selects the data from data1.json or data2.json. Both have keys "A", "B", "C", and "D" only. This means none of the bars are exiting or entering data, they are all just updating values.

I have classes which assign colours to the bars so that those exiting, updating and entering are respectively red, orange and green. Since the values are only updating, all bars should only be orange. This is the behaviour for "A". But the others go "red" as if they are exiting data and "green" as if they are new entering data.

Why are bars "B", "C" and "D" behaving differently to bar "A"? To me bar "A" is correct.

Unfortunately this snippet isn't working. I can't get it to work in jsFiddle either.

But it is on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Bar-Chart-Update-Pattern) and running on [gh-pages](https://shanegibney.github.io/D3-v4-Bar-Chart-Update-Pattern/).

The data is changed using the dropdown menu.

data1.json

```
[{
    "name": "A",
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "D",
    "value": 4
  }
]
```

data2.json

```
[{
    "name": "A",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "D",
    "value": 8
  }
]
```

The index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .container {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  .exit {
    fill: red;
  }

  .update {
    fill: orange;
  }

  .enter {
    fill: green;
  }

  #json {
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Bar-Chart-Update-Pattern">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Data</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="updateFunction('1')" href="# ">data1.json</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="updateFunction('2')" href="#">data2.json</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Bar-Chart-Update-Pattern">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-8" id="race_graph">
      </div>
      <div id="json">
        <!-- <pre class="col-md-4" id="json">hello</pre> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 70,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 80
      },
      width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var data1 = [{
        "name": "A",
        "value": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "C",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "D",
        "value": 4
      }
    ]
    var data2 = [{
        "name": "A",
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "value": 7
      },
      {
        "name": "C",
        "value": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "D",
        "value": 8
      }
    ]

    // set the domains and ranges
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .padding([0.6]);

    // temporal y-scale
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
      .ticks(8);

    // Add main graph svg
    var svg = d3.select("#race_graph")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    // Add groups for main bar chart
    var g0 = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var index = 1;
    updateFunction(index);

    function updateFunction(index) {
      // d3.json("data" + index + ".json", function(error, newdata) {
      newdata = "data" + index;
      // if (error) throw error;
      data = newdata;

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.value = +d.value;
      })

      // To display json in html page
      document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "</pre>";

      update();
      // });
    }

    function update(err, newdata) {

      // set the domains
      x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.name
      }));

      // set domain temporal y-scale
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })]).nice();

      // Add the X Axis
      svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
      svg.select(".x.axis").remove();
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + "," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      // Add the y axis on left
      svg.select(".y.axis").remove();
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(yAxis);

      var t = d3.transition()
        .duration(750);

      // JOIN new data with old elements
      var newRects0 = g0.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data, function(d) {
          return d;
        });

      // EXIT old elements not present in new data
      newRects0.exit()
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return "exit bar";
        }) // fill red
        .transition(d3.transition()
          // .delay(0)
          .duration(750))
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return height;
        }) // old elements which are leaving the chart, their y position transitions to the xaxis
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return 0;
        }) // old elements which are leaving the chart, therir height trasnitions to 0
        .remove();

      // UPDATE old elements present in new data
      newRects0.attr("class", function(d) {
          return "update bar";
        })
        .transition(d3.transition()
          .delay(1000))
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.name);
        }) // old elememnts in new data transition to their new position
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.value)
        }) // old elememnts in new data transition to their y position
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {
          return height - y(d.value)
        }); // old elememnts in new data transition to their correct height

      // ENTER new elements present in new data
      // EXIT and UPDATE above will not apply first time render as there is no change to the data.
      newRects0.enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr("class", "enter bar") // fill green
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.name);
        })
        .attr("y", height) // bars start on xaxis or position y=height
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return 0;
        }) // bars start with zero height
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .transition(d3.transition()
          .delay(2000))
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return y(d.value);
        }) // after the transition bars goes to its correct y position
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {
          return height - y(d.value)
        }); // after transition bar grows to its full height

    }; // end of update() function
  </script>
</body>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `data()` function a key that will stay the same, so it knows which new data is the same as the old data. `d.name` should work better than just returning the whole object. Something like this works for me:

```
var newRects0 = g0.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/markm/d3c2g42L/

Comment: Yes that works and makes sense. So it uses d.name to compare updating data. Thanks